# Linux c++ how to open a program

Tags: c++, linux

How do you make a c++ program open another program in Linux?  Is it similar to in windows with the shell command?

Comment: Use one of the `exec` functions.

Comment: Are you trying to compare Windows+terminal with Linux+C++ here?

Comment: This really isn't hard at all to search.

Comment: Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard C function, `system()` which runs a command and waits for it to finish.

There is a standard POSIX function, `popen()` which runs a command in a new process and returns a pipe connected to the new process. The pipe is usually uni-directional, it can either read or write (some platforms such as BSD allow bidirectional pipes)

Or you can do it manually, by using the POSIX function `fork()` to fork a new process then one of the `exec()` family to replace the process image with a different program.

My preferred way, which I think is by far the easiest, is to use my [Pstreams](http://pstreams.sf.net/) library. This runs a command in a new process and connects pipes to any of its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, using an iostreams-compatible interface.  This gives you less control than `fork` & `exec` (but is much simpler) but more flexibility and safety than `popen`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of **exec** functions: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `system()` standard library call, which is quite similar to the Windows Shell command.  For more control you can use `exec()` and its variants.

Answer (score 0):

Use `execl()` function. It is for C language but it should work fine. For mor info and some example take look  into this : http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you first use the function *fork* to start another process, and then *exec* to exchange the programm the new process is running ( i.e. the programm that wants to start antother programm ) With the one you want to start. Code would look roughly like this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
switch(pid) {
   case 0: // we are the child process
      exec( name of exectuable ); //exact signautre differs
      break;
   case -1: //An error ocurred
      std::cout << "error\n";
}
```

Fork clones the process you are running. They are aboslutely identical, they even run the same programm. The only difference is the returned pid. The calling process gets the pid of the child, the child gets zero. The switch statment determines which of these is the case. Exec replaces the programm the process is running by another programm. From what i can remember, it only keeps file descriptors. Exec has several varaiants with regard to arguments and search path, look them up in the man page.